# Safari crashes on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: safari, ubuntu-14.04, wine

While running the safari browser on ubuntu, when I type some url and press Enter, I am getting the following error.

```
Error in main
Safari crashed.
Click on debug link to get more details
```

Comment: I am running into this exact same issue. Did you ever figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

alright this is how i solve this, open you safari first before doing anything, go to **preference>Security>default space for database Storage** and increase db storage option to maximum ie 500mb.
[image]

Hope this'll help someone.